# What graphic driver should I use in Ubuntu 20.04 for NVIDIA Corporation GF106GL [Quadro 2000]?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

Ubuntu `20.04` offering me two drivers for this graphic card `NVIDIA Corporation GF106GL [Quadro 2000]`

1. Nvidia binary driver 340.108
2. Nvidia 390

So what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal (ctrl-alt-t to start one), type

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

The list includes your Quadro, several possible drivers, one of which had "recommended" on the line.  Use that one. I'd expect the 440, 450, or the 455 would be the recommended., not the 390.  Ensure you run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before looking at drivers.